# Unique ways to arrange people in seats. 4 people, 5 seats

Tags: permutations, combinations

Say that I have 4 people and 5 seats. How many unique ways are there of arranging these 4 people into the five seats?

In questions like this I would use this formula:

$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$

However this would give me -1! in the denominator. How do I interpret this?

$$\frac{4!}{(-1)!}$$

Comment: Perhaps it would make it clearer for you if you imagined that we had a fifth person, $X$ representing the empty seat.  Now you are trying to put $5$ objects in order.

Comment: As @lulu said, the resulting configurations always have an empty chair. You don't really have "people" in the chairs. Chairs will have "occupants," and "No one" in this case is an occupant. It might be easier to think about the chairs as having statuses rather than occupants. 

How you want to proceed depends on whether you care about only the order of the people, or the actual resulting configurations of the chairs. If the people are called $A,B,C,D$ and the empty chair is $X$, is $ABCDX$ different from $ABCXD$? The people are in the same order, but not in the same chairs.

Answer (score 1):

Approaching directly by first principles:

Without loss of generality, the people have names and can be ordered unambiguously according to those names in alphabetical order.  We can then unambiguously refer to the "first" person and "second" person and so on with regards to their alphabetical order.

Choose what seat the first person sits in.  There are $5$ choices

Choose what seat the second person sits in.  There are $4$ remaining choices

Choose what seat the third person sits in.  There are $3$ remaining choices

Choose what seat the fourth person sits in.  There are $2$ remaining choices

Multiplying the number of options at each step together gives us $5\times 4\times 3\times 2$ total possible outcomes.

In general with $n$ chairs and $k$ people this approach gives us a total of $n^{\underline{k}} = \underbrace{n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)}_{k\text{ terms}}$ where this is the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

---

You could just as easily have referred to this with your "formula" if you were to have correctly identified what should play the role of $n$ and what should play the role of $k$.  You mixed them up.  $n=5$ here and $k=4$, giving $\dfrac{5!}{(5-4)!}$ and in general with $n$ chairs and $k$ people giving $\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}$.  Note that this "formula" is merely just another way of writing the falling factorial.

You could also have imagined an extra fifth "person" (*or ghost if you prefer*) that would take the final chair and then unimagined them after, giving $5!$ arrangements here.  Note that if there are many more chairs than people you may need to imagine "*many*" such imaginary people at which point you will need to divide to correct the overcounting.  In general with $n$ chairs and $k$ people (*and thus $n-k$ "imaginary people"*) giving $n!\times \dfrac{1}{(n-k)!}$

You could also have broken into steps by first choosing which four chairs are to be used and then arrange the people within those selected chairs giving $\binom{5}{4}4!$ and in general with $n$ chairs and $k$ people as $\binom{n}{k}k!$

There are many ways to have seen the problem, and even more which I have not listed, but these are the most natural and common in my opinion.